# Using c++ .lib file in WCF or c# wrapper?

Tags: wcf, c++-cli, marshalling, dcom, distributed-system

I have some c++ .lib files and I want to create a WCF service in which all the functions written in lib files can be called and finally can be used in distributed system (web, android, iphone).

## Doubts:

- Do I need a DCOM object to communicate cpp lib to c# and then DCOM dll is called in WCF.
- Does WCF service automatic marshal from cpp to c# (using System.Runtime.InteropServies)

  ### - I am not sure if late binding in WCF can do the magic?

## Some points which I found while rnd.

- I know how to create a dll from .lib file in vc++ but here problem comes to be "Intersect of cpp class functions in c# code." . Example in cpp, I had created a function getData(char* ch). Now how to call this function passing string,say; "Hello World". It gives a error as (can't overload to datatype SByte*). Tried Sbyte.Parse() and Sbyte.TryParse() but no luck.

I am sorry if it sounds confusing but any sort of help in the form of links or sample code will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Abhay

Answer (score 0):

Is C++ library already COM or other component technology or just a C++ code without relation to COM? In former case you can add COM as reference (it must be .dll) to .NET project but you must marshal it yourselves (handle correct COM release). In latter case it is just about correctly using C++/CLI to wrap your native C++ methods and either expose them directly as WCF service or provide the wrapper as a .NET library to WCF service project. Of course you must manually handle string and other objects transition between managed and unmanaged memory but that is what C++/CLI is about.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav Mrnka for your suggestion.There is no COM used in my code and it is simple c++ code library. Can you please provide some link or example how to create a wrapper class and then directly expose them as WCF service.Thanks in advance.